# Passing values through URL using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NqWQ.png

Before viewing my problem. Please, first see the above image.

And my problem is:

> When I click on the first **Subscribe** button. Then it will redirects to amount due page.
>   And my **Amount Due** should be **$7**. Like this for the second and third subscribe button. How can I do this using codeigniter or PHP.

That' it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be done through url, then just pass the due as a parameter like

```
<a href="amountdue/$7">
```

and accept the parameter in the amountdue page like

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

If you are saving the subscription plans in database, simply you can pass the id through the url and then access the id in the PHP page and do your operations based on the id.

Comment: what if i go to url `base_url()./amountdue/$7` !! horror.. its a bit hardcode too

Comment: @karanthakkar..User didn't shared much information. If the dues are stored in database we just need to pass its id upon selection.

Comment: There is any other option. Instead of passing through URL.

Comment: @Jenz totally agree, but i meant to say if i go to url other than `$7` lets say `$5` or `$3` then ? ill land into a page `base_url()./amountdue/$3` !!! hang on there is no such subscription like that.

Comment: @karanthakkar..But the user wants to redirect to another page upon selection, so I think passing id or value through url is only possible.

Comment: Passing values through URL is too much unsecure whenever you have data like amount...etc. You can use forms and by clicking on respective link just assign the value in some hidden field and submit the form via post method. <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="someFunction('$3')">

Comment: @Jenz passing sensitive data in url is insecure as mentioned by gaurav, but if you still want to then you should use encryption.